# How can i get email incoming/outgoing server settings programmatically

Tags: android, email

I have to develop an email application. But I don't know how to get email incoming/outgoing server settings. Can anybody help me?. Thank you!.

Comment: I have to get email programmatically on Android. My customer have multiple email accounts. (for example yahoo, gmail. 163 and so on). I was already developed program that get gmail contents programmatically.

Comment: Typemail(http://www.typeapp.com/) does it. Don't know but it does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design a UI and ask the user to supply the "email incoming/outgoing server settings", which you then store in a file, database, or `SharedPreferences` as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. But I have to get settings without user intervention. Is impossible?

Comment: @bugIsLucky: Android lacks an API for reading minds. Hence, I have no idea how you would expect to get email server settings without user intervention. To put it another way, would you expect to be able to get the user's bank account credentials without user intervention? If not, what is different between email server settings and bank account credentials?

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. You are right. Of course email password need to user intervention. But my idea is how to get email user name, IMAP server name, Security type, Port and SMTP serveer name and so on. My customer have multiple email accounts. You are right. Please help me.

Comment: @bugIsLucky: "But my idea is how to get email user name, IMAP server name, Security type, Port and SMTP serveer name and so on" -- by the user typing them in. To put it another way, would you expect to be able to get the user's bank name, address, and phone number without user intervention? If not, what is different about "email user name, IMAP server name, Security type, Port and SMTP serveer name and so on" and the bank name, address, and phone number?

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. Customer's password is private. but email user name, IMAP server name, Security type, Port and SMTP serveer name was already set up on customer's phone. My idea is only need to user interventin to input password. The other need not to user intervention.

Comment: @bugIsLucky: "email user name, IMAP server name, Security type, Port and SMTP serveer name was already set up on customer's phone" -- first, you have no way of knowing that. Second, you have no way of getting that. No sensible author of an email application is going to publish an API to allow arbitrary other apps to get at this information. While this information is not as sensitive as is the password, it is not the sort of things apps should be handing out to other apps.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. is great help. see you again.